# Regex match Or and Not

Tags: regex

I want to write a regular expression that captures the solutions to a quadratic equation, that is:

to match
`x=1 or x=2` and `x=2 or x=1`

but not match
`x=1 or x=1` and `x=2 or x=2`

I tried 
`x=[12] or x=[21]`

but clearly [12]=[21] since that order doesn't matter.

I tried capturing the first value and using that:
`x=([12]) or x=[\1]`

which gives me the negation of what I want.

My thinking is that I need to match [12] and not \1. Can this be done? And if so, how?

Comment: `x=1 or x=2|x=2 or x=1` maybe?

Comment: That's true, but I was interested in a solution of the form given above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a capturing group on the first character class and restrict the second one with a negative lookahead containing a backreference to that Group 1 value:

```
x=([12]) or x=(?!\1)[21]
```

Probably, a word boundary will be helpful, too (in case you want to make sure you only avoid matching `1` in `1` and not `1` in `100`):

```
x=([12]) or x=(?!\1\b)[21]\b
```

To match any digit(s), replace `[21]` with `[0-9]` or `\d`.

**Details**

- `x=` - a literal substring
- `([12])` - Group 1: either `1` or `2` (`\d+` or `[0-9]+` to match any 1+ digits)
- `or`  - `or` enclosed with spaces
- `x=` - a literal substring
- `(?!\1\b)[21]\b` - a `2` or `1` (replace with `[0-9]+` or `\d+` to match any 1+ digits) that are not equal to the value captured in Group 1 (due to `(?!\1\b)` negative lookahead).

Note that in case your numbers can be glued to words, you will have to replace `\b` word boundaries with `(?!\d)` negative lookahead (no digit right after the current location).

See the [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/jtgjnr/1).

Comment: Thanks! The comments are very helpful. I tried to modify the second example to test if I can match `x=11 or x=12`, that is two digit solutions. I tried by replacing [12] with [11|12] but that doesn't work.

Comment: @Geoff You need `(?:11|12)`, the `(...)` (or `(?:...)`) is a *grouping* construct. The `[...]` is a character class that only matches 1 symbol out of the character set defined inside the brackets. Avoid long lists of alternatives, especially if they start with the same char(s), e.g. you may use `1[12]` to match either `11` or `12`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:

```
x=(\d+) or x=(?!\1)\d+
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rP3lzf/1)**

Comment: The `x=(\d+) or x=(?!\1)\d+` pattern will not match [`x=2 or x=200`](https://regex101.com/r/rP3lzf/2)

Comment: You are right, as always. For this particular example, we can then use [`x=(\d+) or x=(?!\1\b)\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/rP3lzf/4)